# Remove BOM from string in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have string in file, that contains BOM (from UTF-8). I want to convert this string to win-1251 and put it in file.

I trying to remove BOM from string in this way:

```
out.write(l.replace('\uFEFF','\0') + "\n");
```

But it don't work. Why?

Output of this string in win-1251 file:

```
?1,...SOME_TEXT_HERE
```

First "?" sign is illegal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're replacing the BOM with U+0000, rather than with an empty string. You should replace the BOM with the empty string, e.g.

```
out.write(l.replace("\uFEFF", "") + "\n");
```