# Java UTF-8 not working properly for JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, utf-8

I am using spring rest template for getting rest API.

When I try to print the output, I get unwanted Characters.

Here is my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> apiResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,String.class);
        return apiResponse.getBody();
```

Output is:

```
ï»¿{"status":"FAILURE","error_code":"ITI","message":"Invalid Transaction Id","time":"30-03-2017 11:47:32"}
```

After getting this error I added UTF-8 Charecter encoding in the rest client:

```
public static String exicute(String url) {          
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
        ResponseEntity<String> apiResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,String.class);
        return apiResponse.getBody();           
    }
```

After that OUTPUT GOT changed but now **?** in front of the result.

```
?{"status":"FAILURE","error_code":"ITI","message":"Invalid Transaction Id","time":"30-03-2017 11:49:34"}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: this seems like your JSON includes a BOM(Byte-order mark), here's how to remove it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847500/remove-bom-from-string-in-java

Comment: my problem is only 1 api response having this problem .. others are fine

Comment: are all responses from the same service, or is this specific response from another service?

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret all from same service, but 1 api have problem

Comment: @jaghanvarma if only one case can treat it separately and remove first character using string.substring(1) , It is because of UTF-8 with BOM ,

Answer (score 2):

`ï»¿` in front of the message is because the input stream has a byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning of the stream. The byte order mark is a Unicode character often at the beginning of the byte sequence which signals that the following bytes are encoded in UTF-8.

The character itself is often encoded as UTF-8 as well. It is then encoded as `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, and it is often [displayed as `ï»¿`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#/media/File:Table_ascii_extended.png).

> its only use in UTF-8 is to signal at the start that the text stream is encoded in UTF-8

That character is actually not part of the contents itself; instead it is merely a piece of metadata.

**How to fix it?**
The creator of the byte sequence (often a file, but it can also be some byte stream over the network) *should* remove it, in my opinion.

But on the other hand, you can easily remove it by replacing the character by an empty string.

```
string.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

<sub>[code piece copied from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847500/remove-bom-from-string-in-java)</sub>

Comment: is there any Charset for that one

Comment: @jaghanvarma What do you mean?